# ordering array by elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to arrange @plrdet by the values in arr.

when im selecting this way:

```
@plrdet = Player.find_all_by_fid(arr)
```

it returns in the order of the rows in the table, i want it to be ordered by the order of arr.

for example:
Player contains the following attributes: **address**, *age*, uniqnum.

and:

```
arr
```

is an array of the uniqnum.

arr=[**456**,*123*,789]

player=[{NYC,32,123},{BSAS,27,456},{LND,30,789})

the result that im looking for should be from the "find_all"
player=[,{BSAS,27,**456**},{NYC,32,*123*},{LND,30,789})

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem I would try something like this:

**Hash version**

```
players = [{}]
@plrdet.each do |player|
    players << {"adress" => player.adress, "age" => player.age, "fid" => player.fid}
end
players.inspect
```

Now result should be [{"adress" => BSAS, "age" => 27, "fid" => 456},{"adress" => NYC, "age" => 32,"fid" => 123},{"adress" => LND, "age" => 30, "fid" => 789}]

**Array version**

```
players = [[]]
@plrdet.each do |player|
    players << [player.adress, player.age, player.fid]
end
```

Now result should be [[BSAS,27,456],[NYC,32,123],[LND,30,789]]

**Sort**

I think this solution should work but I don't like it and there are maybe better way to solve your problem :

```
sorted_players = [[]] 
arr.each do |arr_fid| 
    sorted_players << players.collect{|player| player if player.include?(arr_fid)} 
end
```

Comment: Thank, but i didnt explained my self proparely.

when im querying @plrdet = Player.find_all_by_fid(arr)
i get what i want but not in the order i want.
i want it to be ordered according to the uniqnum column in the  "arr" order

Comment: I think this solution should work but I don't like it : _sorted_players = [[]]_
_arr.each do |arr_fid|_
 _sorted_players << players.collect{|player| player if player.include?(arr_fid)}_
 _end_

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use [order](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) to sort the results with the query
2. Use [sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) to sort the results in memory

You may use 1. It will be something like:

`@plrdet = Player.find_all_by_fid(arr).order("address")`